# How can Firebase nodes be structured to restrict user access and allow admin to pull report data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Context:** I am putting together a time tracking application using Firebase as my backend. My current node structure has Time Entries and Clients at the root like so:

- **Time Entry**

  - *Entry ID*

    - *UserID*

      - clientID, hours, date, description, etc
- **Clients**

  - *ClientID*

    - name, projects, etc

This structure works fine if I'm just adding and pulling time entries based on the user, but I want to start putting together reports on a per client basis. Currently, this means making a separate HTTP request for each user and then filtering by the clientID to get at the data.

The rule structure for Firebase grants access to all child nodes once access is given to the parent node, so one big list doesn't work as it can't restrict users from seeing or editing each other's entries.

**Question:** Is there a way to structure the nodes that would allow for restricting users to only managing their own time entries, as well as allow for one query to pull all entries tied to a client?

** *The only solution I could come up with was duplicating the entries into a single node used just for reporting purposes, but this doesn't seem like a sustainable option*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AL. your answer was what I went up going with after scouring the docs across the web. Duplicating the data is the best route to take.

The new Firestore beta seems to provided some workarounds to this.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would do this is with Cloud Firestore.

Create a root collection `clients` and a document for each client.  This partitions the data into easily manageable chunks, so that a client admin can see all data for their company.

Within the client document, create a sub-collection called `timeEntries`.  When a user writes to this, they **must** include a `userId` field (you can enforce this in the rules) which is equal to `request.auth.uid`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation

You can now create read rules which allow an admin to query any document in the `timeEntries` sub-collection, but an individual user must query with `userId = request.auth.uid` in order to only return the entries that they have created.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#security_rules_and_query_results

Within your users/{uid} collection or clients/{clientId} collection, you can easily create a flag to identify admin users and check this when reading data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents